# ViewModel for UITableViewCell: Database operations "allowed"?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, viewmodel

I am trying to understand how to correctly use the MVVM pattern in iOS. Lets assume we have a music player app with a playlist like in the following sketch:

[image]

I have a PlaylistViewController and a PlaylistViewModel. Furthermore the cells (SongTableViewCell) have a view model SongCellViewModel which holds the data (song name,..). If the user presses the X button on the TableViewCell I have to delete the song from the database. The cell is calling the following function in the SongCellViewModel:

```
func deleteSongFromPlaylist() {
   DatabaseService.shared.deleteSong(self.song)
}
```

My question: Is it good to do it that way? It doesn't feel right to initiate database operations in the view model of the TableViewCell.

Comment: The view model should tell the model to delete the item from the playlist. The model is then responsible for updating the database. I wouldn't typically have a view model for a cell, just for the tableview and have the cell pass user actions back to the view controller via a closure or a delegation. This also simplifies updating the tableview since you don't have to inform the playlist view model about the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest moving such operations to `PlaylistViewModel` and do all operations from there. It also simplifies implementation of later improvements like showing activity indicator if needed or reloading certain cells or views from there.

I think that `SongCellViewModel` should have a `actionBlock` which will take `enum` with associated values - for example `.select(song)` `.delete(song)` - and this way you can easily communicate between `PlaylistViewModel` and `SongCellViewModel`.

One more suggestion is to use Dependency Injections instead of using `shared` for all type of services.